Monotonicity of integrals of nonnegative measurable functions
Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, $g$ a nonnegative extended real-valued measurable function on $X$, $X_0$ a measurable subset of $X$. Then
$$\int_Xg~d\mu=\int_{X_0}g~\mathrm d\mu~\text{if}~\mu(X\setminus X_0)=0.$$
So, I attempted to create a proof, but I am stuck.
let $g$ and $h$ be nonnegative measurable functions on $X$. Suppose $g\leq h$ a.e on $X$. Let $X_0=\{x\in X: g(x)\leq h(x)\}$. Hence, $X\setminus X_0$ is measurable and has measure zero. Thus, $X_0$ is also a measurable subset of $X$. Let $\varphi$ be a simple function such that $0\leq \varphi\leq g$ on $X$. Since $g\leq h$ on $X_0$, $0\leq \varphi\leq h$ on $X_0$. Now,
$$\begin{align}
\int_X g~d\mu &=\sup~\left\{\int_X\varphi~ \mathrm d\mu:\varphi~\text{is a simple function for which}~0\leq \varphi\leq  g~ \text{on}~X \right\} \\
&=\sup~\left\{\int_{X_0}\varphi~ \mathrm d\mu:\varphi~\text{is a simple function for which}~0\leq \varphi\leq  g~ \text{on}~X \right\}.
\end{align}$$
I am having troubles equating this to the $\sup\{\int_{X_0}\varphi~\mathrm d\mu:\varphi$ is simple for which $0\leq \varphi\leq g$ on $X_0$}. If I get this, I can use the fact that $\phi<h$ on $X_0$. Can anyone show how? Or are there other ways of proving this?

If $A \in \mathcal M$, denote by $\mathbb 1_A$ its indicator/characteristic function. With your notations, we have
$$\int_X g~d\mu = \int_X g\cdot \mathbb 1_{X \backslash X_0} d\mu + \int_X g \cdot \mathbb 1_{X_0} d\mu$$
Now $g \cdot \mathbb 1_{X \backslash X_0}$ is $\mu$-almost everywhere zero (why ?) and you can apply the following lemma :

Lemma : Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space, h a nonnegative extended real-valued measurable function on X. Then :
$$\int_X h~d\mu = 0 \Longleftrightarrow h \text{ is } \mu-\text{a.e zero}$$

to the first integral and the result follows.
